# Change the color of line draw line android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, lines

I'm using this app to draw free lines in android

DrawerView.java

```
public class DrawerView extends View {

public static  Paint paint;
Paint paint2 = new Paint();
public Path path = new Path();
public Path circlePath = new Path();

public static int lineCol = Color.BLUE;

public static boolean isTouchable = false;

public LayoutParams params;


public DrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(lineCol);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

}


public void onButtonPress(){
    // resets the screen
    path.reset();

    // Calls the onDraw() method
    postInvalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!isTouchable){ 
        return false;
    } else {

    // Gives you x and y coordinates on the Event.
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();

    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);

        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
        circlePath.reset();

        circlePath.addCircle(pointX, pointY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        circlePath.reset();

        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    postInvalidate();
    return true;
    }
  }
}
```

DrawLines.java

```
public class DrawLines extends Activity {

DrawerView myView;
public Button btnReset;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.draw_line);

    myView = (DrawerView)findViewById(R.id.custView);

    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // resets the screen
            myView.path.reset();

            // Calls the onDraw() method
            myView.postInvalidate();

        }
    });
}

}
```

draw_line.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clear" />

<com.example.drawline.DrawerView
    android:id="@+id/custView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    custom:lineColor="#ff0099" />
```

It works well with me but I want to be able to select the color of line, so I added a button in draw_line.xml that when press it show a dialog that asks the user to select color. this is the code of dialog

```
public void openSelectColorDialog()
{
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("Select Color");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.military_list);

    int image[] = { R.drawable.black, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.yellow};

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> objArayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> listData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        listData.put("image", Integer.toString(image[i]));

        objArayList.add(listData);

    }

    String[] from = { "image"};
    int[] to = { R.id.list_image };

    SimpleAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, objArayList,
            R.layout.military_list_item, from, to);
    ListView lst1 = (ListView) d.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    lst1.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    lst1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                // the code of color line

                d.dismiss();

            } else if (position == 1) {
                // the code of blue line

                d.dismiss();

            } else {
                // the code of yellow line
                d.dismiss();

            }

            myView.postInvalidate();

        }
    });

    d.show();

}
```

What is the code I have to add to make the color like what I selected ?

consider if I write this code
    DrawerView.paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
the whole line changes its color to the selected color and this is not what I want.
I want that the color of the new line is like what I selected and keep the old lines with its colors.

Hope anyone got my mean.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

the new code is:
ColoredPath.java

```
public class ColoredPath {

private Paint paint;
private Path path = new Path();
private int color;

public ColoredPath() {
    paint = new Paint();
    color = Color.BLACK;

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
}

public ColoredPath(int color) {
    paint = new Paint();

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
}

public void setColor(int color){
    this.color = color;
}

public int getColor(){
    return color;
}


public void setPaint(Paint paint){
    this.paint = paint;
}

public Paint getPaint() {
    return paint;
}

public void setPath(Path path){
    this.path = path;
}

public Path getPath() {
    return path;
}
}
```

DrawerView.java

```
    public class DrawerView extends View {

public Path circlePath = new Path();

public static int LINE_COLOR = 0;

public static boolean isTouchable = false;


public List<ColoredPath> paths = new ArrayList<ColoredPath>();

public ColoredPath currentPath;

public DrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    currentPath = new ColoredPath();
    paths.add(currentPath);


}   

public void newLine(int color){
    System.out.println("in newLine method");
    currentPath = new ColoredPath(color);
    paths.add(currentPath);
    //postInvalidate();
}

public void onButtonPress(){
    // resets the screen
    currentPath.getPath().reset();

    // Calls the onDraw() method
    postInvalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    System.out.println("size of paths: "+paths.size());

    canvas.drawPath(currentPath.getPath(), currentPath.getPaint());
    for(int i = 0; i < paths.size(); ++i) {
          //ColoredPath coloredPath = paths.get(i);
          canvas.drawPath(currentPath.getPath(), currentPath.getPaint());
        }
}


  public Path getLastPath() {
    Path path = new Path();
    for(int i = 0; i < paths.size(); ++i) {
      path.addPath(paths.get(i).getPath());
    }
    return path;
  }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (!isTouchable){ 
        return false;
    } else {

    // Gives you x and y coordinates on the Event.
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();

    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        currentPath.getPath().moveTo(pointX, pointY);
        //getLastPath().moveTo(pointX, pointY);

        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        currentPath.getPath().lineTo(pointX, pointY);
        //getLastPath().lineTo(pointX, pointY);
        circlePath.reset();

        circlePath.addCircle(pointX, pointY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        circlePath.reset();

        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    postInvalidate();
    return true;
    }
}
   }
```

and in MainActivity.java

```
 if (position == 1) {
  // blue
 myView.newLine(Color.BLUE);
 d.dismiss();
}
```

this works well and colors the lines but when I select any color it leads to remove the last line and I want all lines with there colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Path itself doesn't contain any information about it's color (color is managed by Canvas) I would suggest you to create new pair of (Path, Paint) for every new path with different paint and use only current pair in onTouch event. So here is some code which illustrate this idea

```
public class ColoredPath {

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;

    public ColoredPath(Paint paint, Path path) {
        this.paint = paint;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public Paint getPaint() {
        return paint;
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }
}

private List<ColoredPath> paths = new ArrayList<ColoredPath>();

public DrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    //custom paint can be used here
    paths.add(new ColoredPath(new Paint(), new Path()));
}

/////
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for(ColoredPath coloredPath : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(coloredPath.getPath(), coloredPath.getPaint());
    }
}
```

Where paths is `List<ColoredPath>`. And also you need field like `ColoredPath currentPath`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added your code in my DrawerView.java and in onDraw it asks me to initialize the paths as I added List<ColoredPath> paths; before the for loop. How to initialize it? please write the complete suggested code because I'm new in android.

Comment: I wrote List<ColoredPath> paths = new ArrayList<ColoredPath>(); but it not works with me. Hope you answer me asap.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you add `ColoredPath` at start and on every new Color?

Comment: I want you to show me how to initialize the paths and ColoredPath exactly.

Comment: But the paths.add(new Paint(), new Path()); is not fixed with me as add function's arguments are int and ColoredPath object.

Comment: please be patience with me, I'm depressed and it still not works.

Comment: I edited my question to be like what you told me, but how to set the color of line. ad it now not draw anything.

Comment: Are you serious? Have you understood my idea? If not then I can't help you more, I am not going to write everything for you, you need to learn how to write code by yourself.

Comment: I now done like what you told me and now I can draw lines with colors but my new problem is that when I select color it removes the old line and I want all line be as them. could you help me in this?

Comment: You have implement `onDraw` method as I wrote in my answer, because now you're painting only your currentPath.

Comment: Sorry I have another question, how can I remove or erase a specific line in this app?

Comment: just remove it from your `paths` collection